# How to describe putting on a coat

Tags: synonyms, phrasal-verbs, writing, writing-advice, paired-word-requests

Is there a way to "he put on his coat" without actually using the verb "put on"? A friend suggested "he dressed his coat" but it sounds very strange to me.

Comment: After the donnybrook was over Don donned his coat and left.

Comment: _He dressed his coat_ doesn't work. As Hot Licks indicated, there is the word _don_ which has exactly that meaning, but it is not much used in everyday English. I can't think of another word that is common.

Comment: *Grabbed or got* his coat, or anything of the sort, and the reader can figure what he did with the coat.

Comment: "Slipped into his coat", "slid into his coat",  "struggled into his coat", "shrugged his way into his coat", "drew his coat around him", "buttoned himself into his coat", there are others. It depends on what the coat was like, how hard it was for him to put it on and what impression you want to give of the way he did it.

Answer (score 1):

[don](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/don)

> to put on (an article of clothing)

Comment: The is what immediately came to my mind after I read the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider something more descriptive:

> He threw on his coat.

> He slipped on/into his coat.

> He pulled on his coat.

> He flung on his coat.

If you're going for the most neutral verb possible, 'don' is, as other answers/comments have indicated, a correct (and probably comedically archaic) usage.